# How to share a directory on a Linux machine to a Windows machine via NFS?

Tags: linux, windows, mount, network-shares, nfs

What are the full steps one needs to do to mount a directory from a Linux machine as a network drive on a Windows machine via NFS?

---

Incomplete answer:

- Linux side:

  1. Install the NFS server and utilities (`nfs-utils` or your distribution's equivalent).
  2. Create the directory `/srv/nfs`.
  3. Create a new empty directory under `/srv/nfs`, e.g. `files`.
  4. Bind-mount the created directory to the directory containing you want to share, e.g.: `sudo mount --bind /home/user/stuff/files /srv/nfs/files`
  5. Create or edit `/etc/exports`, and add the line:

     ```
     /srv/nfs 192.168.0.0/16(rw,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
     ```

     (the above assumes the Windows machine is on the same LAN as the Linux machine, with the subnet having a 192.168.0.0/16 prefix - adjust as needed).
  6. Start the NFS server (e.g. `sudo systemctl start nfs-server.service`).
- Windows side:

  1. In *Control Panel*, open *Programs and Features*, there find *Add/remove Windows components*, and enable *Services for NFS* and everything under it.
  2. Open a command prompt, and type:

     ```
     mount -o anon \\192.168.0.1\srv\nfs\files Z:
     ```

     (assuming your Linux machine is at 192.168.0.1).
  3. The directory should now be available on the Z: drive. (Type `start Z:` at the command prompt to open it in Explorer).

---

The above instructions seem to be incomplete - I just get a permissions error when attempting to access the mounted drive. Adding the options `insecure` and `anonuid`/`anongid` had no effect.

Comment: samba (SMB / CIFS) != NFS. Feel free to create a similar question for Samba, though, I think it would be a good resource. Also, not sure which search result that query you intended to refer me to - the first result is 5 pages long, which highlights the usefulness of a terse guide like the above (except working, unlike the above!).

Comment: Back to the matter at hand - I did get it working, but now I'm not sure what I changed to get it to work... I may try again with a clean slate and figure it out later.